# I can’t figure out this giant blob of garbled text in my nginx access logs

Tags: nginx, security

```
163.172.4.153 - - [17/Oct/2017:05:51:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 57264 "https://www.mywebsite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" "-“
```

‹�³IäY�ìmsÛ¶–Çßï§ÐäU3]Rø¬N§ÓöÞm»·Ùf6ÙÍîììd( ’ó©$eG}±Ÿ}AJ¶i
´p QvÒ4N"Ëâï� Ï$°Lß3‰k†ƒÿúâNÿXÔSjfy3Ì\ò­ÅÿûßÉ«*þþ~2½ÊSVDk6Çùä×÷ïßN‰I^Ml‹LHàN^¯&¯ÞäÅIM]Óš|³ÈÓ"ªãyÂ¾›üÅËMUÄKVN©i}7ùöª®‹Ùtz{{kÎ›ošüíÓŠEåâjº{£yU§ÉëWÍ'ÿ¹ç¥Þ p 
|>\BqÃÇ¸œrÚÁ¤–5!!
ïÞ,°¦é¶ú3™FË4Îú]À:¤þ×¼\3†Ç±œ*
    ÿF7%…À´*/§¸*Ò-bÉc¼¹Œñ0l@£\FÛ(ôB8ìápp89Š=h%9ZŒ±  Š4ÂApeã9bCH2TWy±œŠ€6%Š2*—Q:*ÃÛ7?Žz}Ô|K¶F’XCÁ“» —2ÆçhæB0.À;ì(…A
$ ˜j[]Š_.¢ßî°Ä-C¢@½+–¤Ø¥Bh)ˆ«[€ Æîû¹[´<ªcf 0Ü,èÔLÀ‚¶Œ   åPÛÀÁîe€ðßhAæKè+®ÃÚäb:fì� ß½€±ìsvÇRa…ÌÈ
À@

There’s plenty more, enough to cross the char limit on ServerFault so I had to [host the whole blob elsewhere.](https://pastebin.com/UAqQ9sFw)

The site is running WordPress 4.8 behind Nginx 1.13.6

**UPDATE**

I opened up the whole blob inside Sublime Text with the proper encoding...
[image]

If I’m not mistaken those are ASCII control characters and my suspicion is that nginx is logging an SSH session?

Am I getting hacked?

Or is my own SSH login somehow being entered into the logs?

Or is my suspicion completely off-base and there’s a better explanation?

Comment: Do you have a `log_format` directive in any of your `nginx` configuration files?

Comment: `$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for”`

Comment: FakeUnicode says possible gzip'ed data https://twitter.com/FakeUnicode/status/920333176081235968

Comment: That’s really interesting, is there something I can do to help further the investigation? I did a verbatim copy-paste from the logs to the pastebin, perhaps I shouldn’t have done that and there’s a better way to preserve the data? Right now, I want to identify what content it is that nginx is serving and if that content is malicious in nature.

Comment: Is it a good idea to turn off gzip encoding inside nginx and see if that request gets logged again?

Comment: following up with encoding: what is the primary language / encoding of the website?

Comment: English(US) and UTF-8 (set via meta charset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have added the `gzip` parameter to your `access_log` directive, which makes nginx use gzip compression on the log file entries when writing to the log file. Also, you didn't delete the old log file after making the change, so the first line is from before the change.

It also means that you cannot use `zcat` or similar utilities to inspect the log file.

I prefer not to use the `gzip` feature with the log files. Just use standard system log rotation functions to rotate log files and optionally compress older log files.

Comment: I haven’t set gzip in the access_log anywhere (just looked at my `nginx -T`) in my current config but perhaps, as you have astutely pointed out, a previous install had that turned on. I did indeed get this data after doing a `cat access.log.*` so you were bang on target on that one as well, terrific answer!

Comment: You can try making a copy of the file, and then removing the first line with `vi` or similar editor which doesn't bother about character encodings. Then you can try `zcat` to the file and you should be able to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: Actually your comment about `cat` was spot on! The problem was me being stupid and doing a `cat access_log.* > all_log`! There was an access_log.gz in the folder so `cat` took the `gz` file along with all the `txt` files and put that into `all_log` as well! Thank you for solving this mystery!